# Где тут ошибка?

Tags: php

У меня на сервере не работал код, я засунул его в компилятор. Компилятор говорит что надо убрать точку с запятой вот тут: `$file = 'Data/Users/'.$_COOKIE['id'].'/img.txt';`

Вот полная версия неработуещего отрывка:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'Data/Users/'.$_COOKIE['id'].'/'.$_FILES['filename']['name']) {
$file = 'Data/Users/'.$_COOKIE['id'].'/img.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($f, $_FILES['filename']['name']);
fclose($f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'Data/Users/' . $_COOKIE['id'] . '/' . $_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
    $file = 'Data/Users/' . $_COOKIE['id'] . '/img.txt';
    $f = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($f, $_FILES['filename']['name']);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Закрывающая скобка ) для if в самой первой строке

Используйте стоящие IDE (программа где вы пишите) для предотвращения подобных ошибок, они очень помогают